# installing a R package in the cluster

Tags: r

I wanted to install some R package in a cluster (with the specific version) to do my analysis, this are my code

> devtools::install_version("lme4", version = "1.1-23",repo = "https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL))

But I get an error message

“Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
Execution halted
”

can anybody guide me, what should I do?

Comment: Check the directory at [lme4] (lib.ugent.be/CRAN//src/contrib/Archive/lme4). No such version exists. It is the current version so a simple `install.packages("lme4)` is all you need.

Comment: but i need this version

Comment: This is the current version. You will get it automatically with the command I gave you earlier. That version will not be moved to the archives (where you were looking for it) until a new version comes out.